# Removing the edges of the unique path $u$ and $v$ of the graph disconnect the vertices $u$ and $v$?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph.
Let $u$ and $v$ belongs at the $V(G)$.

I know that $G$ have exactly one path $P$ of $u$ to $v$.

Is it true that $G-E(P)$ (the obtained graph from removing of the edges of $E(P)$ in $G$) not contains path of $u$ to $v$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that there is a path from $u$ to $v$ in $G-E(P)$, say $Q$. Then since all edges of $Q$ are in $G$ also, $Q$ is also a path from $u$ to $v$ in $G$. Moreover, $P\ne Q$ as no edge of $Q$ is in $E(P)$. So, there are at least two paths from $u$ to $v$ in $G$. This is a contradiction. So, your claim follows, there is no path from $u$ to $v$ in $G-E(P)$.